# get data based on primary key and display in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get data based on primary key and display for EDIT in html page. but i am getting `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` error.
I try to resolve it by looking at other posts but unable to do so.. hope somebody will help in problem.

my forms:

`class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('stuName','stuCity','stuPhone','stuNationality','stuCreatedt')
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('courseId','courseName','enrolledStu','students','dept')
class DeptForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dept
        fields = ('deptId','deptName')`

Models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
 stuName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuPhone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
 stuNationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 stuCreatedt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 def __str__(self):
     return '%s %s %s' % (self.stuName,self.stuCity,self.stuNationality)
```

Class Dept :

```
class Dept(models.Model):
 deptId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 deptName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s' % (self.deptId, self.deptName)
```

class Course

```
class Course(models.Model):
 courseId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 courseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 enrolledStu = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
 students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
 dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseName,self.enrolledStu,self.students,self.dept)
```

urls.py for edit is

url(r'^stuApp/(?P\d+)/$', views.edtStudent, name='edtStudent'),

method for edit inside view.py is :

```
def edtStudent(request,pk):
course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept')
if request.method =="POST":
    form = CourseForm(request.POST,instance=Course)
    if form.is_valid():
       course = form.save(commit=False)
       course.courseName = request.POST['courseName']
       course.enrolledStu = request.Post['enrolledStu']
       course.save()
       course.save_m2m()
       return redirect('liststudent')
else:

    #form = CourseForm()
    #return render(request, 'stuApp/edtStudent.html', {'form':form})
    form = CourseForm(instance=course)
    return render_to_response('edtStudent.html', {'form': form})
```

Html is :

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

it displays log from else but somehow doesn't display anything on html..

Thank you for your time....

Comment: Try : `form = CourseForm(instance=course[0])`

Answer (score 1):

`filter` always returns a queryset. But you need to pass a model instance, not a queryset, to the form. Use `get` instead.

```
course = Course.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('students').select_related('dept').get()
```